# Bounded Laplacian Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> Find the bounded solution of $\triangledown^2u(x,y)=0$ in $D=\{(x,y):x^2+y^2\le 1\}$ assuming that on the boundary of $D, \ \frac{\partial u}{\partial n}$ is equal to $f(\theta)=4\cos\theta-\cos2\theta+cos3\theta.$

I am not sure how to solve this problem? I know I must write the problem in terms of polar coordinates but I am not sure what my boundary conditions or initial conditions are?

How can I set up this PDE correctly?

I have the solution, which is $$u(r,\theta) = A_0+4r\cos(\theta)-\frac{r^2}{2}\cos(2\theta)+\frac{r^3}{3}\cos(3\theta)$$ but I am not sure how it solved.

Comment: Look up "Laplace equation on a disk". Short answer is that separated solutions are of the form $r^n \cos n\theta$ and $r^n\sin n\theta$. So, once you have an expansion of the boundary values into a Fourier series, you can simply multiply the $n$th harmonic by $r^n$ (or by $(r/R)^n$ on a disk of radius $R$).

Comment: @Raff Got ya. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, solutions of the Laplace equation can be written in polar coordinates like this: 
$$
u(r,\theta) =  A_0 +B_0\log r+ \sum_{n=1}^\infty r^n (A_n \cos n\theta+B_n\sin n\theta)
+ \sum_{n=1}^\infty r^{-n} (C_n \cos n\theta+D_n\sin n\theta)
$$
But, $\log r$ and negative powers of $r$ are not acceptable on a disk, since they have a singularity at $r=0$. This leaves 
$$
u(r,\theta) =   A_0  + \sum_{n=1}^\infty r^n (A_n \cos n\theta+B_n\sin n\theta)
\tag{*}$$
It remains to plug $r=$ (radius of the disk) into $(*)$, equate to the given boundary values, and determine the coefficients $A_n, B_n$. In general, this requires the integral formulas for Fourier coefficients; but when the boundary values are presented as a trigonometric sum, you have these coefficients already.